# C++ python library not found. Code Blocks GNU GCC

Tags: c++, python, python-2.7, codeblocks, python-2.x

So this is my first time trying to use python within a C++ program, and i am running into some problems with getting the library linked.

So i use the Code Blocks IDE with the GNU GCC compiler, and i have the following main program:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"starting interpreter."<<endl;
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print 'Im in python!'");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

and my linking settings are as follows (within code blocks GUI for compiler&debugger settings):

```
linker settings:
    link libraries:
        C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a
search directories:
    linker:
        C:\Python27\libs
```

Is there something that i am missing? or am i doing this the wrong way?

Build messages:

```
C:\Users\users_name\Desktop\PythonIntegratedTest\main.cpp|1|error: Python.h: No such file or directory|
C:\Users\users_name\Desktop\PythonIntegratedTest\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\users_name\Desktop\PythonIntegratedTest\main.cpp|9|error: 'Py_Initialize' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\users_name\Desktop\PythonIntegratedTest\main.cpp|10|error: 'PyRun_SimpleString' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\users_name\Desktop\PythonIntegratedTest\main.cpp|11|error: 'Py_Finalize' was not declared in this scope|
```

Comment: You should copy, paste and post the exact error you're getting -- it matters.

Comment: Change *~\libs* to *~\include* in your search directories, pls.

Comment: I tried that, the same error occured :/ do i have to change my linked library aswell?

Comment: Are you sure you changed it at the correct point and the errors keep being exactly the same? For CodeBlocks, goto *Settings - Compiler and debugger - Search directories - Compiler* and add *C:\Python27\include* to the list. This should fix the *Python.h not found* issue and the others along.

Comment: @NiklasR ok, so i changed that, and now im just getting errors about undefined references to the Python functions.

Comment: Ok, great. That means the compiler can now find *Python.h*. But he cannot find the library. The library contains the compiled code for the functions in the *Python.h*, and without that, you can't use the functions. Please take a look at the file *C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a*. I assume it does not exist. On Windows, the library is called *python27.lib*, so you just have to change that in your CodeBlocks settings. Then compiling should succedd.

Comment: Perfection! Could you make that an answer so i can give you your points and to help future people with this same question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says `Python.h: No such file or directory`. This means, the compiler cannot find the requested file. The path in your search directories is not correct. Header-files that need to be *included* are usually in a directory called *include*. For Python on Windows, this is `C:\Python27\include` in your case.

In CodeBlocks, you can modify the include search directories under `Settings - Compiler and debugger - Search directories - Compiler`.

After you've done that, you will get *undefined reference to* errors. The error message tells you, that you have used a function in your code the compiler can not find the implementation for, but only the declaration (in the header file).

The implementation can be either available in a source-file or in a static library. CPython on Windows comes with pre-built static libraries. It is located under `C:\Python27\libs\python26.lib` in your case

After changing that as well, compilation should succeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
main.cpp|1|error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

is a compile-time error because your compiler can't find Python.h in the include search path.  If you were using gcc on the command line, I'd tell you to specify your Python install's include folder, as in:

```
-I/path/to/Python27/include
```

(on my Windows Python 2.7 install, its `C:\Python27\include`)

I'm not sure how you would do this in CodeBlocks but certainly there is a way to specify your "header include paths".

Just note that this isn't the same as "library search path" or "linker search path" -- its specifically for the compiler and the header search locations.